# C# multi-thread huge lag and blocking

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using C# UI to trigger several threads. Each thread represents a single function which may take several minutes to finish.

The UI may trigger the same thread several times and therefore I need to restart the thread several times. However threads cannot be restarted. Therefore, I created a state variable for the thread, when the state is incorrect, the thread will not execute code:

```
    private void FindThread(int nod)
    {
        //Find the minimum reading 
        while (true)
        {
            if (state == MYSTATE.find)
            {
               dowork();
            }

        }
    }
```

However, when two or more threads are working in this way, it seems that the while(true) sentence alone will block the whole program....

In my program, only one thread will perform its task at one time. I am thinking to make a big thread with cases. 
Could I have your suggestions on this? I think there could be better solutions.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to use threadpools for such tasks .. Follow this how-to guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4732ks0.aspx

Comment: How much CPU would you expect the `while` loop to consume if `state` doesn't match `MYSTATE.find`? What would terminate the loop? `nod`?

Comment: @HABO , CPU will not do anything if state does not match. However, it will keep checking if the state matches or not.

Comment: @KCdod Thanks for your reply. I thought ThreadPool are for small threads which do not need much time.

Comment: @richieqianle: that is incorrect. The CPU will keep checking `state` over and over again (which very much is doing something). That's polling and it's generally not a good idea.

Comment: How does it keep checking the state without using the CPU? There isn't even a `sleep` or other delay in the loop. It's the code version of "Are we there yet? Are we there yet? ...". Check the CPU used by a simple console application that contains `while (true) {}` without even involving the CPU in a check,

Comment: @siride ,Hi guys, I understand that the CPU is doing something while(true). What I mean is that it only checks the state, no other work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues related to your question.

First of all you are not starting same thread and I think what you do is start threads with same "thread function" ex- LongTask() [Simple Thread tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/thread)

Secondly, if you have to use multiple threads for a same sort of task , starting a fresh thread and ending is too costly. For such cases you can use thread pools [Thread Pools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4732ks0.aspx)

And the problem you face now is a race condition. May be several threads use same resource [`state` or `MYSTATE.find` ] and update that resource so your condition create a dead lock. [read about deadlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163618.aspx)

Some suggestion -

Use [LOCKS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) to avoid race conditions

```
   private Object thisLock = new Object();

    public void MyThreadMethod()
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
           // Accessing common resources
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1. To restart, I will change the state from "disable" to "find". The thread never dies. 2. I may need to learn more about thread pools. My worry was that it is for small threads. 3. O!!! Yes!!! I think it could be a deadlock..Thanks!

Comment: Accepted, if you have non-ending tasks thread pools may not be suitable. If that's the case have a proper methods to terminate your created threads [rather than using thread.abort() - which is evil IMO]

And yes I guess it's a deadlcock. So use locks when accesing common resources

Comment: Could you explain more about the "proper methods to terminate created threads" ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: A thread execute a specific method. In your case you run an infinite While loop in it. Best way to end the thread is to let the method return [typical return at the end of a method]. So I suggest to use some kind of flag unique to each thread and check it in while. Ex :- While (flag) {//do} , where flag is a Boolean and unique to each thread. And when you need to end the thread, set the flags to false :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! If a flag is set to false, how to start the thread again? The thread needs to be working from time to time and depends on UI totally.

Comment: How to start a fresh thread? I used what you described, the previous thread is not null after the function is finished actually and I cannot restart a new thread using the same thread name.               if (thread== null){
                thread = new Thread(() => FindThread(nod));
                thread.Start();  }

Comment: I make "thread" a global variable, because when the button is clicked twice, I dont want to create two threads.

Comment: Sry, What I mentioned was a proper exiting condition for the whole program. In your main while you can have the flag as I described so at the very end of the program you can use that flag to end the thread.[Set flag to false and join thread so thread will exit]. And for your specific concern, you can use a if condition inside the infinite while where the condition is set on UI button click [A global flag too].

Comment: It seems that I can recreate the thread when the thread is not alive. something like: else if(thread.alive == false){thread = new Thread(() => FindThread(nod)); thread.Start(); } I dont think set the flag in while is a good idea, since the program needs to check all the time for the while sentence, which is a huge waste of resources and cause lags for the program. There are six or seven similar threads in the program.

Comment: Yes exactly, if you implementation support such a thing [Ending thread after job is completed] you may simply re-start the thread :) Thing is I can guide you but I can't give an exact answer to your questions since I don't know the exact requirements. so bare with my answer